# Curl C++ Wrapper retrieve as string

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

is there a C++ Wrapper for libCurl where it is possible to retriev the complete response as a standard c++ string ?

Or any other lightweighted C++ library ?

Comment: Maybe not directly "light-weight", but you could check out http://cpp-netlib.org/ And a remainder: You should be careful when asking for libraries, as such questions are considered off-topic here on SO.

Comment: A few year ago I wrote a C++ wrapper (see [easycurl](https://github.com/jweyrich/easycurl)) for libcurl, but I haven't put any effort into writing documentation, test cases, etc. You may still find it useful though. `easycurl_session req; std::string res = req.get("your URL"); std::cout << res << std::endl;`